# Get values from window location . url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have response url in window.location.href and I need the value for `error`, `error_description` and `state` from it

> http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7916eb9-4404-4cc5-b5a3-ee3211237566%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-05+09%3a19%3a07Z%0d%0alogin_hint%3a+kzahid%40opm.co.uk%0d%0a&state=da2d6e3c-cb6f-1d3b-909b-c6412325b3

I am using following code but getting null value

```
  var messageType = new RegExp('[\?&]' + "error" + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
```

I need find this string from url "The user has forgotten their password"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that your URL parameters are preceded by a `#`, not a `?`.

So, simply replace it and access the parameters using [`URLSearchParams#get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get):

```js
var prevUrl = "http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7916eb9-4404-4cc5-b5a3-ee3211237566%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-05+09%3a19%3a07Z%0d%0alogin_hint%3a+kzahid%40opm.co.uk%0d%0a&state=da2d6e3c-cb6f-1d3b-909b-c6412325b3";
var url = new URL(prevUrl.replace(/#/,'?'));

console.log(url.searchParams.get("error"));
console.log(url.searchParams.get("error_description"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In a (modern) browser you can use the `new URL()` to parse your url and extract query parameters easily.

```
var location_url="http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7916eb9-4404-4cc5-b5a3-ee3211237566%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-05+09%3a19%3a07Z%0d%0alogin_hint%3a+kzahid%40opm.co.uk%0d%0a&state=da2d6e3c-cb6f-1d3b-909b-c6412325b3";

//To make it work you have to replace "/#" with '?' so that new URL() constructor parses the url properly.

location_url=location_url.replace('\/#','?');

var url = new URL(location_url);
var error = url.searchParams.get("error"); 
console.log(error);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split by `&` and then split items by `=`.

```js
// what you would do:
//const hash = location.hash;

// for demo purposes:
const hash = '#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7916eb9-4404-4cc5-b5a3-ee3211237566%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-05+09%3a19%3a07Z%0d%0alogin_hint%3a+kzahid%40opm.co.uk%0d%0a&state=da2d6e3c-cb6f-1d3b-909b-c6412325b3';

const hashParams = hash.substr(1).split('&')
  .reduce((obj, groupStr) =>
    Object.assign(obj, {
      [groupStr.split('=')[0]]: groupStr.split('=')[1]
    }), {});
  
console.log(hashParams);
console.log(hashParams.error_description);
```

Answer (score 1):

use reg like this:

```
    let url='http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7916eb9-4404-4cc5-b5a3-ee3211237566%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-05+09%3a19%3a07Z%0d%0alogin_hint%3a+kzahid%40opm.co.uk%0d%0a&state=da2d6e3c-cb6f-1d3b-909b-c6412325b3';
    let result=url.match(/error_description=([\s\S]*?)\./)[1].split('+');
    result.shift();
    console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use a RegExp even though might be an overkill having the new options from the previous answers, you can use a RegExp like this:

```js
const regex = /(error|error_description)=(.+?)&/g;
const str = `http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7916eb9-4404-4cc5-b5a3-ee3211237566%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-05+09%3a19%3a07Z%0d%0alogin_hint%3a+kzahid%40opm.co.uk%0d%0a&state=da2d6e3c-cb6f-1d3b-909b-c6412325b3`;

let matches;
while ((matches = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (matches.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    matches.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      if (groupIndex === 1 )
        console.log(`Param: ${match}`);
       if (groupIndex === 2 )
        console.log(`Value: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

```
/(error|error_description)=(.+?)&/g
```

Here you have 2 capture groups inside the full match, so you can get separatedly the parameter name and its value.

`(error|error_description)` -> will match either error or error_description

`(.+?)` -> will match from 1 to any characters until it finds the next character match, stated in this case by `&`, as few times as possible and expanding as needed

The `g` (global modifier) will allow to return all the matches found.